# Sum map values in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a map that structure like this:

```
"Alex": [Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=1),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=4),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=5),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=1)],

"John": [Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=2),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=2),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=1),
        Work(workPlace="workPlace", years=6)]
```

What is the best way to sum the values?

For exampe, How can i sum all the years of Alex and John?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're mostly looking for the [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) function, which allows you to transform a map's values, while keeping its keys. You could use this something like this:

```
val people: Map<String, List<Work>> = ...
val peopleToSumOfYears: Map<String, Int> = 
        people.mapValues { (name, works) -> works.sumOf { it.years } }
```

Comment: `sumBy` is now deprecasted in favour of `sumOf`

Answer (score 3):

```
val sum = map.values.sum()
```

This should work faster with approx. O(N) complexity because values are already stored in a list. And `mapValues` with `sumOf` is about O(2N) because of 2 loops inside.